# How can I implement the graph shown in the picture below using rechart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recharts

[image]

how can i implement this image using recharts? please help...

Comment: Looks like BarChart but in vertical orientation to me... Did you attempt using vertical barchart? https://recharts.org/en-US/api/BarChart

Comment: @Kartoos yes.. I am going to use  a vertical bar chart. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [BarChart](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/BarChart) by setting `layout='vertical'`. Here is an example to get you started:

```js
const App = () => {
  const rangeData = [
    {
      "day": "05-01",
      "temperature": 10
    },
    {
      "day": "05-02",
      "temperature": 15
    },
    {
      "day": "05-03",
      "temperature": 12
    }
  ];
  
                              
  return <BarChart layout='vertical' barSize={10} width={800} height={200} data={rangeData} margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}} >
  <XAxis type='number' />
  <YAxis type='category' dataKey="day" />
  <Tooltip />
  <Bar dataKey="temperature" fill="#8884d8"  />
</BarChart>
};

export default App;
```

[image: vertical-bar-chart]

Comment: I know that I need to use a bar chart. The key is the blue and yellow rectangles in the picture, but I'm not sure which API to use for that.